# Word Wrap in Editor Console

Tags: unity, console

I'm working as an educator - I am wondering is there any way to wrap the text of lines output from the Unity editor *console*?...

Thanks!

Comment: I don't believe there is anything you can do to change how it looks.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the number of lines of text that appear, up to 10. See here:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Console.html#LineCount

> To control how many lines of each entry are visible in the list, click the Console menu button, and select **Log Entry > [X] Lines** from the menu, where **[X]** is the number of lines you wish to display for each entry.
>   [image: screenshot]

If that’s not good enough, you can always write your own console window, but that seems like overkill. The short version is, use a subclass off `EditorWindow` and listen to `Application.logMessageReceived`.

There are also various custom consoles on the asset store, some of which have line wrapping. They are not all free though. I just googled “[unity editor better console](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity%20editor%20better%20console)” and found a bunch.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I found one called NG Console that I am going to try for the time being. I am sure a new one with UI Elements will come along at some point...